# How to convert List<Class> to Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, class

```
public class myClass {
    private String myVar1;
    private String myVar2;
}

List<myClass> list = generateListWithGson();

System.out.println(list.toString());
// returns
[
  myClass(myVar1=OneDummyString, myVar2=TwoDummyString),
  myClass(myVar1=OneDummyString, myVar2=TwoDummyString),
  ...
]
```

I desire to format it like this:

```
// desired output:
[
  {
    "myVar1" : "OneDummyString",
    "myVar2" : "TwoDummyString",
  },
  {
    "myVar1" : "OneDummyString",
    "myVar2" : "TwoDummyString",
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Why do you need to reinvent the Swagger wheel?

Comment: :D @JoeC just need to send this data as formatted.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for json representation of the list. Try Jackson or library. Example - http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-serialization-list/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println( new Gson().toJson(list) );
```

Should work

Answer (score -1):

```
Object[] objectArray = lst.toArray();
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

Answer (score -2):

Override the `toString()` method of myClass.
Then convert your `List` to an array of myClass objects (see the answer of Dev).